# Project Tango - 3D Reconstruction

Tags: c++, google-project-tango, 3d-reconstruction

I'm trying to use the [C 3D Reconstruction Library](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/reconstruction/reference/) to get a mesh from the Tango device.
In the [Mesh Building Functions](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/reconstruction/reference/group/mesh-building-functions) there's a summary of the flow to use, which shows that I have to call the `Tango3DR_update` function several times and then call the `Tango3DR_extractFullMesh` to get the mesh.

The problem is that `Tango3DR_update` needs the `Tango3DR_PointCloud` object which I don't see how I get.
I can create an empty `Tango3DR_PointCloud` using `Tango3DR_PointCloud_create`, but I don't see anywhere how I fill it with real data.

Does anyone know how to get this object?
Or anyone knows if there's any example / sample code using this library? I didn't find any.

Thanks, 
  Oren

Answer (score 2):

You should fill the Tango3DR_PointCloud from the TangoXYZij you receive in OnXYZijAvailableRouter. Same thing for the pose struct.

```
// -- point cloud
Tango3DR_PointCloud cloud;
cloud.num_points = xyz_ij->xyz_count;
cloud.points = new Tango3DR_Vector4[cloud.num_points];
for (int i = 0; i < cloud.num_points; ++i) {
  cloud.points[i][0] = xyz_ij->xyz[i][0];
  cloud.points[i][1] = xyz_ij->xyz[i][1];
  cloud.points[i][2] = xyz_ij->xyz[i][2];
  // last is confidence
  cloud.points[i][3] = 1;
}
cloud.timestamp = xyz_ij->timestamp;
```

(Do not forget to `delete []` cloud.points once you're done)

The only official example I could find is in the [Unity examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/0bbfeabcf763e86c8e41d67c4ab4b77ad734a6d9/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Core/Scripts/TangoWrappers/Tango3DReconstruction.cs). They use the C API but called from C#.